# How to check if a cdrom is in the tray remotely (via ssh)?

Tags: mount, cd, devices, cd-drive, mountpoint

I have a server running Ubuntu 10.04 (it's on the other side of the world and I haven't built up the wherewithal to upgrade it remotely yet) and I have been told that there is a CD in one of it's two CD drives.  I want to rip an image of the cd and then download it to my local computer (I don't need help with either of these steps).

However, I cannot seem to confirm whether or not there actually is a CD in the drive as I was told.  It did not automatically mount anywhere (which I'm thinking might just be a result of it being a headless server not running X, nautilus, or any of the other nice user friendly things).

There are two CD drives connected via SCSI:

```
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: WDC WD400EB-75CP Rev: 06.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: Lite-On  Model: LTN486S 48x Max  Rev: YDS6
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
  Vendor: SAMSUNG  Model: CD-R/RW SW-248F  Rev: R602
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

However when I try mounting either of these devices (and every other device that could possibly be the cd-drive), it says `no medium found`:

```
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/scd1 /cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr1
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/scd0 /cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr1
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom1 /cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrw /cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr1
```

Here are the contents of my `/dev` folder:

```
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ ls /dev
agpgart          loop6               ram6      tty10  tty38  tty8
austinvpn        loop7               ram7      tty11  tty39  tty9
block            lp0                 ram8      tty12  tty4   ttyS0
bsg              mapper              ram9      tty13  tty40  ttyS1
btrfs-control    mcelog              random    tty14  tty41  ttyS2
bus              mem                 rfkill    tty15  tty42  ttyS3
cdrom            net                 root      tty16  tty43  urandom
cdrom1           network_latency     rtc       tty17  tty44  usbmon0
cdrw             network_throughput  rtc0      tty18  tty45  usbmon1
char             null                scd0      tty19  tty46  usbmon2
console          oldmem              scd1      tty2   tty47  usbmon3
core             parport0            sda       tty20  tty48  usbmon4
cpu_dma_latency  pktcdvd             sda1      tty21  tty49  vcs
disk             port                sda2      tty22  tty5   vcs1
dri              ppp                 sda5      tty23  tty50  vcs2
ecryptfs         psaux               sg0       tty24  tty51  vcs3
fb0              ptmx                sg1       tty25  tty52  vcs4
fd               pts                 sg2       tty26  tty53  vcs5
full             ram0                shm       tty27  tty54  vcs6
fuse             ram1                snapshot  tty28  tty55  vcs7
hpet             ram10               snd       tty29  tty56  vcsa
input            ram11               sndstat   tty3   tty57  vcsa1
kmsg             ram12               sr0       tty30  tty58  vcsa2
log              ram13               sr1       tty31  tty59  vcsa3
loop0            ram14               stderr    tty32  tty6   vcsa4
loop1            ram15               stdin     tty33  tty60  vcsa5
loop2            ram2                stdout    tty34  tty61  vcsa6
loop3            ram3                tty       tty35  tty62  vcsa7
loop4            ram4                tty0      tty36  tty63  vga_arbiter
loop5            ram5                tty1      tty37  tty7   zero
```

And here is my `fstab` file:

```
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/austinvpn-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=ed5520ae-c690-4ce6-881e-3598f299be06 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/austinvpn-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Am I missing something/doing something wrong, or is there just no CD in the drive or is the drive possibly broken?  Is there any nice command to list devices with mountable media?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output isn't quite as pretty as yours but it doesn't require you to install anything:

```
$ sudo lshw | awk '/\*-cd/,/con/' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'

*-cdrom                   
description: DVD-RAM writer
product: DVD RW AD-7240S
vendor: Optiarc
physical id: 0.0.0
bus info: scsi@8:0.0.0
logical name: /dev/sr0
version: 1.00
capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
*-cdrom
description: DVD-RAM writer
physical id: 0.0.0
bus info: scsi@9:0.0.0
logical name: /dev/cdrom
logical name: /dev/cdrw
logical name: /dev/dvd
logical name: /dev/dvdrw
logical name: /dev/sr1
logical name: /media/X3_Linux
capabilities: audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 state=mounted status=ready
```

Comment: I was wondering if there would be a way to do it with installed software.  I love questions like this because you can see so many different ways to do the same thing.  I'd wager that creative use of `grep`, regular expressions, and another pipe or two could make this more "pretty"--but who knows if it'd be worth the time :P

Answer (score 3):

### Using hwinfo:

I think I just answered my own questions using the `hwinfo` tool.  This tool searches for and lists a bunch of useful information about the various devices on your computer.

It can be installed with `sudo apt-get install hwinfo`.

It can also be run with the `--<hwitem>` flag to only list info for a particular type of hardware (ie. cd drives) here are the options for this flag:

```
   --<hwitem>
          Probe for the particular hardware item. Available hardware items
          are:  all,  bios,  block,  bluetooth,  braille,  bridge, camera,
          cdrom, chipcard,  cpu,  disk,  dsl,  dvb,  fingerprint,  floppy,
          framebuffer,  gfxcard,  hub,  ide,  isapnp, isdn, joystick, key‐
          board, memory, modem, monitor, mouse, netcard,  network,  parti‐
          tion,  pci,  pcmcia, pcmcia-ctrl, pppoe, printer, scanner, scsi,
          smp, sound, storage-ctrl, sys, tape,  tv,  usb,  usb-ctrl,  vbe,
          wlan, and zip.
```

Using the `cdrom` flag I can find the information I need.

```
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ sudo hwinfo --cdrom
15: SCSI 100.0: 10602 CD-ROM                                    
  [Created at block.247]
  Unique ID: KD9E.skIhcO_MyD1
  Parent ID: 3p2J.7RBlinTaF34
  SysFS ID: /class/block/sr0
  SysFS BusID: 1:0:0:0
  SysFS Device Link: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0
  Hardware Class: cdrom
  Model: "Lite-On LTN486S 48x Max"
  Vendor: "Lite-On"
  Device: "LTN486S 48x Max"
  Revision: "YDS6"
  Driver: "ata_piix", "sr"
  Device File: /dev/sr0 (/dev/sg1)
  Device Files: /dev/sr0, /dev/block/11:0, /dev/scd0, /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.1-scsi-1:0:0:0, /dev/cdrom1
  Device Number: block 11:0 (char 21:1)
  Drive status: no medium
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #9 (IDE interface)
  Drive Speed: 48

16: SCSI 101.0: 10602 CD-ROM
  [Created at block.247]
  Unique ID: nOPI.WcCe56A4L50
  Parent ID: 3p2J.7RBlinTaF34
  SysFS ID: /class/block/sr1
  SysFS BusID: 1:0:1:0
  SysFS Device Link: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host1/target1:0:1/1:0:1:0
  Hardware Class: cdrom
  Model: "SAMSUNG CD-R/RW SW-248F"
  Vendor: "SAMSUNG"
  Device: "CD-R/RW SW-248F"
  Revision: "R602"
  Driver: "ata_piix", "sr"
  Device File: /dev/sr1 (/dev/sg2)
  Device Files: /dev/sr1, /dev/block/11:1, /dev/scd1, /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.1-scsi-1:0:1:0, /dev/cdrom, /dev/cdrw
  Device Number: block 11:1 (char 21:2)
  Drive status: no medium
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #9 (IDE interface)
  Drive Speed: 48
```

As you can see, it reports, `Drive status: no medium` for both drives--appearing to confirm that the CD is either not in the drive, the CD is unrecognizable, or the drive is broken.

### Using hwinfo to find drive status:

If you didn't want to look through all the info `hwinfo` lists, you could further automate the process with the following command:

`sudo hwinfo --cdrom | grep 'Drive status:'`

Which will quickly return whether there are CDs in any of the drives.

```
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ sudo hwinfo --cdrom | grep 'Drive status:'
  Drive status: no medium
  Drive status: no medium
```

I'm looking to see if there is a way to `grep` the Model name at the same time, and I'll update this answer when I figure it out.

Hope this can help someone else!

**edit:**

Here is a slightly more useful command that will output the model name and device file as well (so if a medium is present, you will know which drive it is present in and where you can mount it from/ rip an image from).

```
sudo hwinfo --cdrom | grep -e 'Model' -e 'Drive status:' -e 'Device File:'
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
austin@austinvpn:/proc/scsi$ sudo hwinfo --cdrom | grep -e 'Model' -e 'Drive status:' -e 'Device File:'
  Model: "Lite-On LTN486S 48x Max"
  Device File: /dev/sr0 (/dev/sg1)
  Drive status: no medium
  Model: "SAMSUNG CD-R/RW SW-248F"
  Device File: /dev/sr1 (/dev/sg2)
  Drive status: no medium
```